# jQuery: How can I get the class of a certain element that's inside another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have a table named `unitTables` with some rows. It is one of many similar tables on the webpage. In those rows is a class called `selected`, which I want to retrieve for a variable. The other tables on the page also use the `selected` class, so I need to retrieve this *specific* instance of `selected`.

In plain JavaScript, the way to find it is:

```
var table = document.getElementById('unitTables');
var selected = table.getElementsByClassName("selected");
```

**What's the equivalent to the above two rows in jQuery?**

I know I can rewrite the first row like this:

```
var table = $('#unitTables');
```

But I know I can't do the exact same thing to the next row, as I need to use to id of `unitTables` in order to get the specific `selected` row in that table. Currently I have:

```
var selected = from.$(".selected");
```

Which throws an `Uncaught TypeError: from.$ is not a function.` error, so I know that's not the correct syntax.

**What's the best approach?**

Comment: The way to find it in js is `document.querySelectorAll("#unitTables .selected")` or just `$$("#unitTables .selected")` in the dev tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var table = document.getElementById('unitTables');
> var selected = table.getElementsByClassName("selected");
> ```
>
> What's the equivalent to the above two rows in jQuery?

```
var selected = $("#unitTables .selected");
```

(Except `selected` will be a jQuery object around the matched set of elements, instead of a collection.)

The [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) (`jQuery` or [usually] `$`) looks up elements via [CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/). So in this case, a descendant selector that looks for `.selected` within `#unitTables`.

Comment: Didn't realize you could combine ID and class selectors like that! This works perfectly, thanks.